# Validating user email ID during sign up

Tags: users

We are making a accounting software and would like to know how we can use a open source API  or query to validate user email id by sending email to the specific email id and getting a activation response from the same using a weblink.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use any sort of API or query. If you're goal is to validate email, it's built into Drupal's core account settings (Configuration > People > Account settings). Just make sure the ***Require e-mail verification...*** checkbox is ticked on the form page.

[image: Drupal register account settings]

Comment: Good idea. I did a quick screen grab of Drupal site I already had open. It's been refreshed with a more accurate image & additional instructions.

Comment: Much better (or should I say "way less misleading"?) ... +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using contributed module https://www.drupal.org/project/user_email_verification